# An efficient way to insert a cover (first page) for batches of documents?

Tags: preamble, covers, atbegindocument

I have more than 50 **.tex** files of similar contents, all of which loads **preload.tex**.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, scheme = plain, UTF8]{ctexart}
\input{preload.tex}
\begin{document}
contents contents contents contents contents 
contents contents contents contents contents 
contents contents contents contents contents 
\end{document}
```

I wish to add a **cover.tex** something like

```
\begin{center}
cover stuff and info....
\end{center}

lots of other stuff
but all within a page
\vfill
\clearpage
```

I could add an extra line using Notepadd++ for all the .tex files to become

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, scheme = plain, UTF8]{ctexart}
\input{preload.tex}
\begin{document}
\input{cover.tex}
contents contents contents contents contents 
contents contents contents contents contents 
contents contents contents contents contents 
\end{document}
```

But is there a more efficient way to do so, by adding something in the **preload.tex** ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add

```
\AddToHook{begindocument/end}{\input{cover}}
```

anywhere inside `preload.tex`, which will `\input{cover}` immediately after `\begin{document}`.